# Why startActivityForResult not working?

Tags: android, arraylist, startactivityforresult

I'm using `startActivityForResult` to return value from **Activity B** to **Activity A**. But when the save `button` in **B** is clicked, it does not back to **Activity A**.  Can someone help me to figure out the problem ?

**Activity B**

```
  save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {  // return values to previous activity
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent returnIntent=new Intent();
                Project=project.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Description=description.getText().toString();
                progress=seekBar.getProgress();
                returnIntent.putExtra("Project",Project);
                returnIntent.putExtra("Description", Description);
               returnIntent.putExtra("progress",progress);
                returnIntent.putExtra("TimeIn", TimeIn);
                returnIntent.putExtra("TimeOut",TimeOut);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                Log.e("d","d");

            }
        });
```

**Activity A**

```
     public static final int PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
      public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 2;

  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.addDetails:
                View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.addDetails); 
                PopupMenu po = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView); //for drop-down menu
                po.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_details, po.getMenu());
                po.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if ("Add Work Details".equals(item.getTitle())) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), Add_Details_Information.class);  // go to B
                            startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                po.show(); //showing popup menu
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from B
           if(requestCode==PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE)
           {
                    ReceiveProject = data.getStringExtra("Project");
                    ReceiveDescription = data.getStringExtra("Description");
                    ReceiveProgress = data.getStringExtra("progress");
                    ReceiveTimeIn = data.getStringExtra("TimeIn");
                    ReceiveTimeOut = data.getStringExtra("TimeOut");

                    ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults = GetSearchResults(weather, date, status, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut);
                    listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this,searchResults));
            }
            else if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
           {

           }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not finishing your activity after the call to `setResult` in Activity B. Make sure you call `finish()`.